# Ordering of conditions in multi-way conditional constructs

Tags: programming-languages

Most programming languages provide multi-way conditional constructs (like `cond` in Lisp, guards in Haskell, etc) that allow one to define program behavior according to different conditions.  But most of them also implies a default top-down ordering: the next condition is checked only when all preceding conditions are unsatisfied.  I wonder if there is any work on conditional constructs that does not follow this convention but rather automatically sort the conditions according to some order.  I can foresee how hard it is to get conditions independent.  Maybe it is not feasible anyway?

Comment: Can you be more specific about  what your question is?  It is certainly possible to define a different sort of multi-way conditional construct.  If you are asking for a language with that construct, that's probably off-topic -- requests for language recommendations are probably off-topic.  (There are also languages with multi-way conditionals where the conditionals must be disjoint.)  If you are asking if it is possible to define such a construct, it is certainly possible; many languages will even let you define your own control structure.  Can you articulate a more narrowly scoped question?

Comment: Dijkstra's [Guarded Programming Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language) has such an if, one of the true branches is selected at random.

Answer (score -1):

On what basis you want to sort out conditions conditions are not specific. If they are specific then you may sort out the conditions to not follow top down approach.

And conditions are the only thing that decide which condition next to be tested.
That is they handle the flow of your code and one condition is dependent on other.